# Getting a full stack web application to work (MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, gulp

I have followed this entire tutorial at http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-tv-show-tracker-using-angularjs-nodejs-and-mongodb/ to create a TV Show web application. However, towards the final part I started getting errors and despite trying to solve them and looking online, I got stuck.

So then I tried to test it again, getting all code from the official source - the github project page at [github.com/sahat/tvshow-tracker]. Tried running again, no success as well.

Here is the [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSXGN.jpg) I get:
1) Cannot find module 'gulp-ng-annotate'
2) Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at makeSkinClass

I find it very strange because I have all node packages installed as well as MongoDB, Express, AngularJS and NodeJS

Comment: When you cloned the git repo, did you make sure to run `npm install` afterwards to install dependencies?

Comment: @mscdex I did but apparetly mongoskin@1.4.13 requires a mongodb peer, how can that be the case when I have the lastest version of mongodb installed? [link] (http://imgur.com/a/uUilH)

Comment: what does `npm ls --depth=0 mongodb` show?

Comment: @mscdex it shows this http://imgur.com/a/2WTnS

Comment: It looks like `mongodb` is not installed then. I'm not sure why it showed the other packages though. Did you try explicitly doing `npm install mongodb` from the same directory?

Comment: @mscdex yes I did, with no success though. Maybe mongoskin 1.4.13 is incompatible with the version (2.2.9) of mongodb I have?

Comment: That could be. You might try upgrading `mongoskin` (there may be breakage though), or downgrading `mongodb` to the last 1.x version as a last resort.